# New Google Play Console: where to upload mapping.txt?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-console

I can't figure out where to upload mapping.txt in the new Google Play Console.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To upload a deobfuscation:

1. Open the Play Console.
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, select Release > App bundle explorer.
4. Select the Downloads tab, and scroll down to the 'Assets' section. Click the upload arrow for the mapping file or the debug symbols as applicable to upload the deobfuscation for the version of your app.

You can also get details on [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?_ga=2.62020459.655307998.1601901472-2143941983.1590658958)

Comment: Thanks but not my question. I am speaking about the NEW console.

Comment: @Regis_AG ah my apologies. please check the new instructions for new play console.

Comment: Thanks ! Could hardly be more hidden... I don't like this new console.

Answer (score 18):

It's under a bundle options menu:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can upload mapping.txt in **Google Play Console New UI** in this way

Select Release > Production > Upload ReTrace mapping file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `aab` format, it will save you the hustle to do it manually.