# App working as an APK but when released through play store it crashes

Tags: android, proguard

I understand many times this is an issue with proguard, I am not very familiar with this I have posted my build gradle and proguard I hope someone can help me as I am getting no crash reports either so I feel a little in the dark.
build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {

    def versionMajor = 1
    def versionMinor = 1
    def versionPatch = 26

    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode versionMajor * 1000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
                }
            }

        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug{
            resValue "string", "app_version", "${defaultConfig.versionName}"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "google_maps_key", "Release_API_KEY"
            resValue "string", "app_version", "${defaultConfig.versionName}"
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        //enabled = true;
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:29.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    implementation files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jdxf.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jna-5.5.0.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0"
    // implementation files('libs/opencsv-2.1-1.0.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.1"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation 'org.jgrapht:jgrapht-io:1.4.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tinkerpop/tinkerpop
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tinkerpop', name: 'tinkerpop', version: '3.4.6', ext: 'pom'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tinkerpop/tinkergraph-gremlin
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.apache.tinkerpop', name: 'tinkergraph-gremlin', version: '3.4.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tinkerpop', name: 'tinkergraph-gremlin', version: '3.4.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'


    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.6.0'

    def nav_version = "2.3.1"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Dynamic Feature Module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"
    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    def room_version = "2.2.4"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

    // Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.stream/stax-api
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.stream', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0-2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/aalto-xml
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'aalto-xml', version: '1.2.2'

    //Email
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.4'

    //okhttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.6'

    //Json
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    //seekarc
    implementation 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'

    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
    // For developers using AndroidX in their applications
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'

}
```

proguard-rules (Which is empty)

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

If there is any way I get debug report out or understand the issue it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The crash logs are available in the google play console of your app in the 'Quality' / 'Android vitals' / 'Crashes and ANR' section. It will list the crashes and include a stack trace for each one. Unfortunately if the code is obfuscated with proguard the stack trace might not provide the full class/method names until you [upload the mapping.txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64208297/new-google-play-console-where-to-upload-mapping-txt)